# combination network

Tags: information-theory

Can any one help me find a reference about how to describe the connectivity between the nodes (H relays) and users in combination network ? I mean how exactly I can draw the connection for any number of H nodes and any number of users and connectivity degree r?

Note: for combination network with connectivity degree r the number of users is equal to $\binom{H}{r}$.

What I want to know for any H and r I choose how to describe the connectivity ? I only found these two examples for H = 4 and H =5 but I cannot find any general describtion for the connectivity between H and users.

[image] [image]

Comment: What's a combination network?  Please define your terms.  What do you mean by "how to describe the connectivity"?  What kind of answer are you looking for?  What do you mean by drawing the connections?  Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing?  Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what  you are asking.

Comment: I still don't understand the question (I'm not sure what "describe the connectivity" means, nor what the definition of "combination network" is).  Perhaps someone else will.  It might help to share with us the context where you encountered this concept/term, and where you got the pictures from.